# How to manually construct a SOAP envelope in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, soap

I am trying to manually construct a SOAP envelope in C#. I initially went down the route of building it up via a StringBuilder and adding it to an XmlDocument via the LoadXml method. However upon execution I am getting an exception along the lines of:

> System.Xml.XmlException : The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A,
>   cannot be included in a name. Line 1, position 200.

The envelope I am trying to create is:

```
<soap:Envelope 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XmlSchema">
    <soap:Header>
        <wsrp:path
            soap:actor="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/actor/next"
            soap:mustUnderstand="1"
            xmlns:wsrp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/rp">
        <wsrp:action>
            http://abcd.com/Webservices
        </wsrp:action>
        <wsrp:to>
        http://abcd.com/Webservices.asmx
        </wsrp:to>
        <wsrp:id>
    uuid:aaaaa0a7-9e46-432b-8f1b-35037077601f
    </wsrp:id>
        </wsrp:path>
        <wsu:Timestamp
        xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/utility">
            <wsu:Created>
            2012-11-30T10:38:13z
            </wsu:Created>
            <wsu:Expires>
                2012-11-30T11:38:13z
            </wsu:Expires>
        </wsu:Timestamp>
        <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/secext">
            <wsse:UsernameToken 
            wsu:Id="SecurityToken-00c26e1a-3b3b-400f-a99a-3aa54cf8c8ff" 
                xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/utility">
            <wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="wsse:PasswordText">password</wsse:Password>
            <wsse:Nonce>NBzqolcwIZrAOYw1vLyucDM3sQQ=</wsse:Nonce>
            <wsu:Created>2012-11-30T10:38:13z</wsu:Created>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
       </wsse:Security>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <MethodName xmlns="http://abcd.com/Webservices">
            <ValueField>Ford</ValueField>
        </MethodName>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I am struggling to understand why the compiler is unhappy with the ':'. Is there a better way to do this/what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `StringBuilder` is one of the most awkward possible ways to construct XML. Use `XDocument`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the input. FYI, the solution that worked for me was to prefix the string with the '@' symbol, and instead of using the \" escape sequence for the double quotes, I went for "" (i.e. two sets of double quotes wherever an escape sequence would be required) - works a treat.